# Let $f, g$ be continuous functions in $[0,\infty)$. Prove that $M=\max({f(x), g(x)})$ is integrable

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f, g$ be continuous functions in $[0,\infty)$. I want to prove that $M = \max({f(x), g(x)})$ is integrable in every closed interval. Is that statement trivial?

$f,g$ are both integrable in every closed interval since they are continuous, but the same can not be said about $M$.

All I know is that $M$ is blocked in every closed interval. What else can I say about $M$ in a closed interval?

Comment: Why can't you say the same about $M$? The function $\max$, regarded as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, hence so is $M$.

Comment: In fact, it is sufficient that $f,g$ be merely integrable on every compact interval, but the proof is more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact $M$ is also continuous, to prove this it suffices to note that $max(f,g)=\frac{| f(x)-g(x)|}{2}+\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}$, each summand can be proven to be continuous rather easily, perhaps the toughest past is to prove that if $h$ is continuous then so is $|h|$.

Comment: If $h$ is continuous, then since $|x|$, is continuous, it follows that $|h|$ is continuous (composition of continuous functions yields a continuous function).

Comment: good point, you mean for proving the last part right?

Comment: Yes, for the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to consider the well known limit

$$\max(f,g)(x) =\lim_{k\to \infty}\{(f(x)^k + g(x)^k)^{\frac{1}{k}}\}$$

Which is true as long as we limit ourselves to $f(x), g(x) \geq 0$, this is trivially not a problem if they are bounded below as we can then just add their minimum to ensure to raise above 0.

The function is a sequence of additions and compositions of continous functions which all preserve continouity.

Comment: So, you are claiming the limit is uniform?

Comment: @WillM. Good question. I don't have a proof that it is. Do you think it is?

Comment: If the limit is only pointwise, the limit can be whatever regardless of how nice the sequence may be. So...

Comment: This only works if $f,g$ are non negative. However, it is straightforward to show that $\max$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: I am probably a bit too rusty and tired to try make a proof, but do you know any proof involving Fourier transforms? I was thinking linearity and integer powers becoming convolutions. I probably should instead be thinking of epsilons to find something a bit more straight?